# onclick form shows, but want other element to hide

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I have this..

```
<button class="movebutton" onclick="jQuery('.moon-form').show();"></button>
```

Which basically shows the form when you click the button.

Though when you click the button and the form shows, I want another element with the id #thetable to hide

So i thought I could do this

```
<button class="movebutton" onclick="jQuery('.moon-form').show();jQuery('#thetable').hide();"></button>
```

But I was wrong.

any input?

Comment: That _looks_ like it should work. Does `#thetable` exist? Can it be hidden in other ways?

Comment: yes thetable does exist.. <table id#thetable>content</table>

but with that command everything is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of using inline:

```
$('.movebutton').click(function(){
    $('.moon-form').show();
    $('#thetable').hide();
});
```

Make sure `thetable` has an ID attribute since you are using `#`

**From the comments, you have:**

```
<table id#thetable>content</table>
```

It should be:

```
<table id="thetable">content</table>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qE3x8/1)**

Comment: I was trying this <script type="text/javascript">
$('.movebutton').click(function(){
$('.moon-form').show();
});

</script> but for some reason it won't work.. it wont pop up my form, but when i do it online it works fine

Comment: Make sure you are embedding jquery library and your script is after the html

Comment: of course that is the first thing i checked, weird how the inline javascript works but not when i move it to a function

Comment: Do you have a demo link? cause it doesn't make sense that it is not working

Comment: for some reason I had to add jQuery instead of the $ there was a conflict somewhere